# Python Selenium Webdriver: how to select more than one element using get_attribute

Tags: python, selenium, getattribute

I'm trying to find the urls on a given page using the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.listing-title a').get_attribute('href')
```

This works well enough to grab the first url. However, I can't figure out how to get the other href attributes on the page. I tried adding an `s` to `element`:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.listing-title a').get_attribute('href')
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, `find_elements_by_css_selector`  returns a list so I need to loop over it:

```
x = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.listing-title a')
for each in x:
    print each.get_attribute('href')
```